# How to perform the Build in TFS2010? What is the Logic should we adopt and How to get a files from TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

Currently we are using StarTeam to perform the build as well as versioning. we planned to migrate startteam to TFS2010. We have some script for perform the build. i wanted to change this script according to my requirement. i gone through the TFS but i had lot more confusion.

in StarTeam, we will get a files from "Ready to Build" label and perform the build. In TFS, how we are going to get a files from TFS? What concept should i use to get a files and perform the build? i have gone through the lot of commands like get, check-in, checkout etc..

If we use "tf get" command, we can get all the files from TFS but i have a clarification on that. shall i get all the files from TFS for every build? i hope, this is unnecessary headache.. correct me if i am wrong..

how we perform the build in TFS? i have read some types of build such as manual, gatedcheckin, Continuous Integration and schedule.

Is there any relationship between branch and build activities?

In TFS, What is the meaning of Workspace?

Comment: You have too many questions for a single question on [so]. One question per question, please.

Answer (score 1):

As said, many questions in one. Hope this helps along the way:

1. A workspace is a mapping between the server and a local storage,
   similar to checkout in Subversion, view in ClearCase, etc.
2. "TF get" normally only fetches those files that have changed since
   last update. You can force it to fetch everything - and sometimes
   have to - but its not normally done.
3. [Team Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the recommended system to build with when using TFS. It can take some time to get into (Windows Workflow-based), but is quite powerful. There are default process definitions that set up the most common actions for you.
4. By default, you can't control whether to build by setting a certain label, but you can define that only this label should be used when builds are triggered. Labels in TFS work [a little differently](http://iworkonsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/04/tfs-labels.html) compared to other VCS, though, so maybe there's an 'opportunity' to re-think your build process along the way. If you're set on using a label as before, you'll need to build a [Custom build activity](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx).